# Restoring sheet size closes workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, restore

I have a situation where one particular workbook will open maximized, and then if I hit the restore button it just seems to close the workbook. The workbook is actually open, but invisible. I've already checked the Visible property and it is true, and have played around a lot with this with no good results. Any ideas?

version: 2010 Pro 32-bit in Windows 7 Pro

Comment: Restore? As in the maximize button, right? Not as in "restore last copy". And you're referring to the workbook inside excel, not excel's window? Is there any code in the workbook, like using `ActiveWindow.WindowState` to trigger something?

Comment: Yes, the restore button in regards to sizing. Yes, I'm referring to the Excel workbook, not Excel. The only ActiveWindow commands are `.SelectedSheets.Printout`, `.ScrollColumn` and `.ScrollRow`.

Comment: Are there any macros? What does "played around" mean? What specifically have you tried?

Comment: Yes, plenty of code behind. I've tried everything I could find, too much to list (or remember). Checked all the settings and played with sizing.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out some of the modules to see if it's fixed, at least to narrow it down if it's code?

Comment: @Raystafarian, didn't do it. It gets more interesting though. I've found that the workbook is still open, and I have a formula selected in the formula bar, but there is nothing to see. I went to the immediate window and it said that the Workbook was Visible. editing question.

Comment: I'm sure you checked this, but I have to ask - is screenupdating still true? What about the window just being out of visible range? And if you open a different notebook - is it visible? I'm wondering if maybe the UI got turned off or something. Or maybe something is running without `DoEvents`? Is the workbook protected at all? Sorry about recommenting.

Comment: @Raystafarian, I finally found a good link that talks about the problem and  I can now at least make the sheet reappear, though I have to do it every time. I'll post an answer when I get a chance to completely go through it. https://smurfonspreadsheets.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/excel-2007-workbook-window-not-visible/

Comment: That's strange - you might want to try to set the coordinates of the workbook on restore that way it might stop happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out this has been an Excel bug for a long time. There are quite a few solutions that will sometimes work for people. The best link/thread I found was: https://smurfonspreadsheets.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/excel-2007-workbook-window-not-visible/.

To fix the spreadsheet I first had to bring it into view after hitting restore and it disappearing. To do this got to the View tab and hit 'Arrange All' then just pick 'Tiled' and check the 'Windows of active workbook' box, then hit ok.

At this point for me it was restored in a non-maximized state, I then saved it and then closed it. When I re-opened the book it was in the restored state.

Some other reasons/solutions that others have mentioned are addin issues and inadvertent hiding.